# Blazor WebAssembly HTML Capture Image from Webcam

Tags: javascript, html, browser, blazor, webcam

When using an HTML input element like this on the Mobile it automatically open the camera and the user have the possibility to take a photo with the camera:

```
<input id="captureCameraInput" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

However, on Desktop this instead simply open a File Browse dialog. Is it possible to capture an image in the same manner but from the connected Webcam instead?

Comment: [blazor webcam capture](https://wellsb.com/csharp/aspnet/blazor-webcam-capture)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand its possible to implement this. Just wanted to understand if its possible to have this functionality out-of-the-box since it is working out-of-the-box on Mobile devices.